# OpenGL Tiles/Blitting/Clipping

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, tiles, clipping

In OpenGL, how can I select an area from an image-file that was loaded using `IMG_Load()`?
(I am working on a tilemap for a *simple* 2D game)

I'm using the following principle to load an image-file into a texture:

```
GLuint loadTexture( const std::string &fileName ) {

    SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load(fileName.c_str());

    unsigned object(0);                        
    glGenTextures(1, &object);                 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, object);   

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image->w, image->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);

    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    return object;
}
```

I then use the following to actually draw the texture in my rendering-part:

```
glColor4ub(255,255,255,255);                
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);      
glBegin(GL_QUADS);                          
glTexCoord2d(0,0);  glVertex2f(x,y);
glTexCoord2d(1,0);  glVertex2f(x+w,y);
glTexCoord2d(1,1);  glVertex2f(x+w,y+h);
glTexCoord2d(0,1);  glVertex2f(x,y+h);
glEnd();
```

*Now what I need is a function that allows me to select certain rectangular parts from the `GLuint` that I get from calling `loadTexture( const std::string &fileName )`, such that I can then use the above code to bind these parts to rectangles and then draw them to the screen. Something like:*

```
GLuint getTileTexture( GLuint spritesheet, int x, int y, int w, int h )
```

Comment: Thank you. What do I need to put as the last argument in my case? `glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, y, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, const GLvoid * data);` I don't have the SDL_Surface anymore, I just have the GLuint that I got from calling `loadTexture()`.  Could you write a short example please?

Answer (score 4):

Go ahead and load the entire collage into a texture.  Then select a subset of it using `glTexCoord` when you render your geometry.

`glTexSubImage2D` will not help in any way.  It allows you to add more than one file to a single texture, not create multiple textures from a single file.

Example code:

```
void RenderSprite( GLuint spritesheet, unsigned spritex, unsigned spritey, unsigned texturew, unsigned textureh, int x, int y, int w, int h )
{
    glColor4ub(255,255,255,255);                
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spritesheet);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);                          
    glTexCoord2d(spritex/(double)texturew,spritey/(double)textureh);
    glVertex2f(x,y);
    glTexCoord2d((spritex+w)/(double)texturew,spritey/(double)textureh);
    glVertex2f(x+w,y);
    glTexCoord2d((spritex+w)/(double)texturew,(spritey+h)/(double)textureh);
    glVertex2f(x+w,y+h);
    glTexCoord2d(spritex/(double)texturew,(spritey+h)/(double)textureh);
    glVertex2f(x,y+h);
    glEnd(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works :) Just one question though, since `unsigned texturew, unsigned textureh` refer to the dimensions of the spritesheet, would it be possible to get these from the `GLuint spritesheet` itself? That would be so much more comfortable?

Comment: @Ben: You can call [`glGetTexLevelParameter`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexLevelParameter.xml) and pass `GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH` or `GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT`.  But it's much more efficient just to keep track of these on the CPU, instead of fetching them back from the GPU every time.  You might want to make a small struct that combines the texture ID (`GLuint`) and the width and height, so you can pass them around together.

Answer (score 2):

Although Ben Voigt's answer is the usual way to go, if you really want an extra texture for the tiles (which may help with filtering at the edges) you can use `glGetTexImage` and play a bit with the `glPixelStore` parameters:

```
GLuint getTileTexture(GLuint spritesheet, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spritesheet);

    // first we fetch the complete texture
    GLint width, height;
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &width);
    glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, &height);
    GLubyte *data = new GLubyte[width*height*4];
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    // now we take only a sub-rectangle from this data
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, /*filter+wrapping*/, /*whatever*/);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, width);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, RGBA, w, h, 0, 
        GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data+4*(y*width+x));

    // clean up
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
    delete[] data;
    return texture;
}
```

But keep in mind, that this function always reads the whole texture atlas into CPU memory and then copies a sub-part into the new smaller texture. So it would be a good idea to create all needed sprite textures in one go and only read the data in once. In this case you can also just drop the atlas texture completely and only read the image into system memory with `IMG_Load` to distribute it into the individual sprite textures. Or, if you really need the large texture, then at least use a PBO to copy its data into (with `GL_DYNAMIC_COPY` usage or something the like), so it need not leave the GPU memory.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm not quite sure if I *"really want an extra texture for the tiles"*. So far I have had every texture in a separate image-file. What I've done now is combine multiple textures into one image-file (spritesheet), e.g. one sheet per character or level. The only reason I wanted the `GLuint` to be returned was because my logic was structured this way (from the separate-images version). But I've changed it now. So which version would you recommend for me to use? How does Ben's version behave compared to yours, anything to watch out for?

Comment: @Ben I think Ben's version is more advanced (and the one you might want to accept, although you can still up-vote mine :)). This way you don't have to switch texture all the time. You might get problems if the texture gets too large (although up to 4096x4096 you should be fine, or more on newer hardware) or you might get artifacts at the edges of the sub-textures, especially when using linear filtering (not to speak of mip-mapping), because these are no longer recognised as texture-edges, as they are inside the image. But these problems can be solved (and have been multiple times on SO).

Comment: Thank you. I've upvoted yours already ;) I'm using Ben's version and so far it works fine for me. Do you maybe know if I can get the image-dimensions from the `GLuint spritesheet` straightforwardly for inside of the `RenderSprite()` function? Do the first four lines in your function do that?

Comment: @Ben You can, I've done this in my code (the `glGetTexLevelParameteriv` calls), but I would not suggest to do this each time you render a sprite, as it calls back to the driver. Querying it once (or just remembering it from the loading) is the better solution. You don't need to put it in the function arguments if you don't want, you can just make a class to store all information, or better, use vertex arrays/buffers for your sprites so you only have to compute the texCoords once (along with the many other advantages). But I won't elaborate on VBOs now.